# ffmpeg keep connection if network source down

Tags: ffmpeg

I know this question has been asked infinite times, but it has not been answered with a decent answer infinite times as well.

How to make ffmpeg keep working even if source becomes unavailable? VLC waits until connection comes back again, why ffmepg does not have such functionality?

I have tried with:

```
-reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4962 -timeout 2000000000
```

but none works as expected. FFmpeg quits after only few seconds. I don't want to restart ffmpeg if connection interrupts because I need output HLS fragments to be available. Restarting ffmpeg makes fragments to be overwritten from the beginning.

Answer (score 8):

FFmpeg command line arguments are position sensitive, so maybe you are not adding them in the right position. Try to put those options before the input.
Example:

```
ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2 -i input -c:v copy -c:a copy outputfile.m3u8
```

'reconnect_delay_max' range is [0 - 4294]

It worked for me.

Comment: I already use reconnecting parameters before the input URL. FFmpeg version is the latest.

Comment: I'm also using the latest version of ffmpeg in your option the 'reconnect_delay_max value need to be between [0 - 4294] yours is 4962 try with a lower value

Comment: Ok even with 4294 it makes no difference. Once the HTTP source is down it quits with:
`[http @ 0x1f986c0] Will reconnect at 26390596 error=Success.
[http @ 0x1f986c0] Will reconnect at 0 error=Success.
    Last message repeated 2 times`

Comment: Yes I know with 4962 it will not work, try this -reconnect_delay_max 2 just to test it, and if it doesn't work can you copy paste the whole command.

Comment: It resists 2 seconds, but are not enough.
This is the whole command:
`/bin/ffmpeg -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2000 -timeout 2000000000 -y -thread_queue_size 5512 -nostats -nostdin -hide_banner -fflags +genpts -probesize 10000000 -analyzeduration 15000000 -i http://127.0.0.1:5555/video1 -strict -2 -dn -c copy -hls_flags delete_segments -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 30 /root/list.m3u8`

Comment: I tested your command with a live stream as an input there's no problem with the reconnect part. so maybe your problem is from the input , is your input a simple file or a live stream???  so can you try with this link as an input http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8

Comment: It's a live stream and it's a problematic one. That's why I need ffmpeg keep working even if the stream is not available for 30 minutes. Two seconds are not enough. -reconnect_delay_max 3600 promises that there will be one hour of retries but it quits after only ~4 seconds.

Comment: try to to remove the timeout and use -reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 2 (for now,just  to test) and please remove -nostats (for now) and when ffmpeg is down can you copy paste the log.
did you try the link  and does it stop when you reconnect?

Comment: This is the output with my stream:
`[http @ 0x2ca3680] Will reconnect at 38228956 error=Success.=N/A speed=2.22x
[http @ 0x2ca3680] Will reconnect at 0 error=Success.
http://127.0.0.1:5555/video1: Input/output erroreed=1.76x
frame= 1069 fps= 34 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:00:54.58 bitrate=N/A speed=1.76x   
video:34245kB audio:2000kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown`
I haven't tested your stream because I don't know how to interrupt the stream connection to apple.com. With iptables?

Comment: you can simply remove the ethernet cable for a short period of time,or if you are connected remotely to a server try iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -dport 80 -j DROP and thenremove the rule with iptables -D INPUT -i eth0 -dport 80 -j DROP normaly this would block the http response
be carefull with the iptables command I don't want to mess with your server So don't use it it you are not sure. but technically it should work

Comment: -sport 80 not -dport 80 my bad :)

Comment: The same with your stream, the only difference is ffmpeg quits on reconnect and not when the connection is interrupted:
After `iptables -A OUTPUT -d devimages.apple.com -j DROP` ffmpeg is still active but after `iptables -D OUTPUT -d devimages.apple.com -j DROP` ffmpeg quits with: `Last message repeated 4 times
frame=52748 fps=224 q=-1.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:30:01.82 bitrate=N/A speed=7.67x   
video:86904kB audio:1299kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown`

Comment: I have this ffmpeg `ffmpeg version 2.8.11-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers`. Unfortunately it reports `Unrecognized option` for every containing reconnect clause.

Comment: None of these options exist anymore.

Comment: @KenSharp these reconnect options are only available for http inputs.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg DOES NOT reconnect if the interruption lasts more than 4 seconds. When network session is lost ffmpeg quits.

The reason for this is that apparently the variable holding the maximum reconnect is 32-bits in size and contains a number which it divides by 1,000,000 to get a millisecond count.  Hence the maximum wait is 2^32 / 1000000 = 4294.9673 milliseconds or 4.294 seconds.

Comment: This is not always true. Ffmpeg will stall sometimes, output halted, connection closed but the proccess is still alive. Try to suspend and resume connection. For me it happens also if the server i am connecting to is stalling for some reason, connection closed in log, but process is alive.

Comment: Not always true, sometimes? Is your theory reproducible?

Comment: This was a long time ago, but with poor connections it will still happen, yes, I believe. Difficult to reproduce unless the right circumstances are there.

Comment: The `timeout` parameter is expressed in seconds.

Answer (score 1):

I have solution for connection down for TCP issues!
Just add option [timeout](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#rtsp) ( in microseconds )

```
ffmpeg -timeout 10000000 \
-i rtsp://input_ip/h264 \
-c copy \
-f flv rtmp://output_ip
```

Comment: `Set socket TCP I/O timeout in microseconds.` It's not clear how this will help.

Comment: The `timeout` is expressed in seconds.